# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound muted on simulator xCode 6 GM

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I run the following code on simulator and I don't get any sound:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pageflip" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) soundUrl, &_soundEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundEffect);
```

The code has been successfully tested on xCode 5 and iOS 7. Libraries imported as required.

I've logged the soundPath and it returns the correct location on the filesystem.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an issue with the simulator. On a device it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue now. My AudioServicesPlaySystemSound was working until the XCode update to 6.0.1. One could assume that there is something broken in the update.

Comment: Actually, I recently learned that this is an issue with the simulator. Once I tested on the device it worked as before. No changes needed.