# No sound on iOS simulator testing vs iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

With Xcode 6.0.1 and iOS Simulator 8.0 (550.1), I get no sound on any simulated device running iOS 8.0.  It still works on all earlier (simulated) iOSes, and works on the only testing device I have upgraded to iOS 8.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread, I experienced the same exact issue.

[AudioServicesPlaySystemSound muted on simulator xCode 6 GM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859337/audioservicesplaysystemsound-muted-on-simulator-xcode-6-gm)